# Django template - How to match model datefield with a date in date generator?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In my models.py Task can have multiple Employer so I use ManyToManyField

In my views.py I got a date generator - it return range of 2 weeks from current day.

So here is my template

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans 'employer_id' %}</th>
                {% for i in date_range %}
                <th>{{ i }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for employer in employers %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ employer.employer_id }}</td>
                {% for t in employer.task_set.all %}
                        <td>{{ t }}</td>
                    {% empty %}
                        <td>0</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I need is when I create a Task and assign it to employers, it should show me in the html table a start_date of Task of each employers for specific days.

So far I got this with codes above:
[image]

^date of tasks of these employers are not matching with days in the table header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
            {% for t in employer.task_set.all %}
                    <td>{{ t }}</td>
                {% empty %}
                    <td>0</td>
            {% endfor %}
```

you need to iterate over the dates again, since you're not creating `<td>`'s for each date.

```
{% for i in date_range %}
{% for t in employer.task_set.all %}
{% if t.start_date == i %}
    <td>{{ t }}</td>
{% else %}
    <td>-</td>
{% endif %}
{% empty %}
   <td>0</td>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```